# Configure team site libraries to sync automatically not working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using the "Configure team site libraries to sync automatically" GPO to add automatically a SharePoint site to our working environment.

The GP writes correctly the entry under HKCU\Software\policies\Microsoft\OneDrive\TenantAutoMount

But after waiting couple of days, the site still does not show in File Explorer.

Our working environment are Windows Server 2016. Could it be the problem?
I would assume not because I can add manually the site if I sync manually.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Christophe

Comment: Are you on SharePoint Online or on-Orem

Answer (score 0):

As said in this article: [Configure team site libraries to sync automatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy#configure-team-site-libraries-to-sync-automatically),

> To use this setting, the computer must be running Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709) or later

I'm afraid this setting is not applicable to Windows Server 2016.